# Cumulative Sum When rows have the same value sql sql server

Tags: sql, sum

I'd like to do cumulative sum of the column **SubTotal** to get a cumulative **RunningTotal** column. But I noticed that if rows have the same values, the cumulative sum doesn't work. e.g. In the below example, the row 5 and row 6 have the same SubTotal value of 838.9178. Because of that, the RunningTotal column doesn't sum up for row 5 and row 6.

[image: example]

How can i fix this issue? I expect to get the results like below:

[image: expected]

Below please find my query. Many thanks in advance!

```
select YEAR(OrderDate) as FiscalYear,
       REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(12), OrderDate,1), ' ', '-') as OrderDate,
       SubTotal,
       SUM (SubTotal) OVER (partition by YEAR(OrderDate) ORDER BY OrderDate,SubTotal ) AS RunningTotal
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
where YEAR(OrderDate)=2012 or YEAR(OrderDate)=2013
order by YEAR(OrderDate),OrderDate;
```

Comment: Actually I believe you'd want the 2nd cell to stay 2894.3139 but the first one to be 2055.3961, but I think it's going to have issues because the rows are identical and it wouldn't know which would come first so it adds both values and gives the same cumulative for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `row` windowing clause or a stable sort.  Try this:

```
   SUM(SubTotal) OVER (partition by YEAR(OrderDate) ORDER BY OrderDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningTotal
```

Or, if you have a unique id (UniqueId for example) on the row:

```
   SUM(SubTotal) OVER (partition by YEAR(OrderDate) ORDER BY OrderDate, UniqueId) AS RunningTotal
```

The issue is that the default windowing clause uses `RANGE BETWEEN`, which is not what you want.